# How to hide the status bar for a particular page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

For a specific page, I'm trying to hide the statusbar and make the content fullscreen but it doesn't seem to work.

general setting in appcomponent.ts .

```
//for most pages
if (core.isPlatform(OsType.CORDOVA)) {
        this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
        this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
        this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#0076b2');
 }
```

code in specific page:
some-page.ts

```
//for specific page
 ionViewDidLoad() {
    if (this.core.isPlatform(OsType.CORDOVA)) {
      this.statusBar.hide();
      this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
    }
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    if (this.core.isPlatform(OsType.CORDOVA)) {
      this.statusBar.show();
      this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
    }
  }
```

my result is always with the blue Statusbar visible:
[image]